# import-gpo : The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002) while importing a LGPO backup to GPO using GPMC

Tags: powershell, active-directory, gpo

I have a computer with policies applied and I want to export that policies to apply them on AD

I'm trying to import a LGPO backup created like this: `$backUpFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path $LGPO -name` in a AD domain.

When importing the backup  `import-gpo -BackupId FACCA114-6E57-4027-AB08-D891F66A4A24 -TargetName test -path C:\temp\backup -CreateIfNeeded` im getting the folling error:

*import-gpo : The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)*

The file exist on directory, I'm running on administrator and have fullControl rights on file

When trying to import a gpo backup made on that same domain works fine. This means a LGPO cannot be imported as a GPO?

manifest.xml of the backup:

```
<Backups xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/GPOOperations/Manifest" xmlns:mfst="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/GPOOperations/Manifest" mfst:version="1.0">
   <BackupInst xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/GPOOperations/Manifest">
      <GPOGuid><![CDATA[{FACCA114-6E57-4027-AB08-D891F66A4A24}]]></GPOGuid><GPODomain><![CDAT[contoso.test]]></GPODomain>
      <GPODomainGuid><![CDATA[{8d345ac4-636f-4d69-8650-335cb5d903a9}]]></GPODomainGuid>
      <GPODomainController><![CDATA[DC01.contoso.test]]></GPODomainController>
      <BackupTime><![CDATA[2023-02-07T12:02:54]]></BackupTime>
      <ID><![CDATA[{FACCA114-6E57-4027-AB08-D891F66A4A24}]]></ID>
      <Comment><![CDATA[Backup GPO created by LGPO.exe]]></Comment>
      <GPODisplayName><![CDATA[Local Policy Export]]></GPODisplayName>
    </BackupInst>
</Backups>
```

Comment: Problem is either a credential issue of the file does not exist.  First check with File Explorer to see if file exists.  It it in the temp folder and may get deleted.  If file exists try opening with notepad to see if you have read permission.  If above works than you do not have admin rights inside PS.  So start PS by right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: @jdweng as I had specified the file exits and I have full control: "The file exist on directory, I'm running on administrator and have fullControl rights on file"

Comment: @jdweng and also I had specified that I was running as admin

Comment: Check the event viewer for additional info.  Was same admin used to create the file?  Group Policy is a special type of admin.  You may need higher level admin credentials to perform the command.

Comment: @jdweng I'm logged as admin in both computers although on is a windows 10 and the other, the domain server is a windows server 2016

Comment: Is the admin the same account?  The computer have to share the same password server and be in the same Group.  You probably have Group Policy enforced on the network.